# What is the name of this pine tree?

Tags: identification, trees, pines

I live in Northern Canada. I am looking to find the right trees to plant in the backyard. I took some pictures of the type of trees I like to plant but have no idea what they are called.

[image]

[image]

(The above 2 pictures were taken from the same location)

[image]

(The above pic was taken from a second location)

[image]

(The above pic was taken from a third location)

Note that I am not entirely sure if the tree in the last picture is the same as the others. If they are different I would like to know all their names, as I think they look great.

I checked some google images, and I think they might be Scots Pine. Please confirm if they are indeed Scots Pine.

Comment: For a correct identification we need photo of the leaves (needles): number per group and length are characteristics. Photo of cones and barks sometimes helps. As you seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pines_by_region#New_World there are many possibilities.

Comment: ... and yes, the top 3 look like they probably are Scots pine.  I wonder if the 4th might be some kind of spruce but I sure can't tell definitely from the photo.  Scots pine grows well in most of Canada, though just how far north they thrive I don't know.  You are using a good approach of seeing what already grows well in your area.  You might look for a cone under one of these trees and take it to a local nursery.